# Moving dae around with camera

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouseevent

So I tried to adding the code to move the object with the mouse, but that didn't worked :s . I already looked around, but everywhere I look, this code works for them?

Also, I would like, if you press the button, the camera would 'fly' to the location, now it just bumps to it!

Thank you for you help!
really appreciated!

The HTML (just standard)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Map</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ap.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="../lib/Three_r49.js"></script>
<script src="ColladaLoader.js"></script>
<script src="orbitcontrols.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="tekst">
<h1>De tweede slag op ieper</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, toen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen overleefd maar is ook, vrijwel onveranderd, overgenomen in elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 populair geworden met de introductie van Letraset vellen met Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus Pag</p>
<button><a href="#" id="testButton">TEST</a></button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (function(){

    //controls
    var controls;

    var width  = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    //move variables
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
    controls.target.set( 0, 0, 0 );

    // renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( width, height );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // scene
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // camera
    // set a camera

    //camera variables - for easy acces
    var viewAngle = 60;
    var width  = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var near   = 0.01;
    var far    = 1000;

    var aspect = width / height;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( viewAngle, aspect, near, far );
    camera.position.z = 10;
    scene.add( camera );


    // light
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1.5 );
    light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 ).normalize();
    scene.add( light );

    var light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    light2.position.set( -1, -1, -1 ).normalize();
    scene.add( light2 );

    //collada
    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
    loader.load( '../map/mapoorlog.dae', function colladaReady( collada ) {
        var dae = collada.scene;
        scene.add( dae );   
    });

    // renderer
    function render() {
      requestAnimationFrame(arguments.callee);
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
    };

    //buttonInteractin
    var testButton = document.getElementById('testButton');
    testButton.onclick = function ()
    {
      camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 0));
    };

    //animate
    function animate() {
    controls.update();
    }

    //init
    function init() {
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
    }

    render();
    animate();
    init();

}), false);
```

Comment: Would it work if I used trackballcontrols?

Comment: The code looks correct. Could you create a jsfiddle for it?